# How to edit several database entries efficiently from JSF web application?

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, java-ee-6

I have several database tables that the user should be able to add, edit and remove entries from the web application.
Also the input must be validated before persisting it.

Now I could simply make a table and put labeled input fields in there, but the result would be far from DRY and a horror to maintain. Composite components make this just a bit better. Is there any alternative I do not see which could reduce a lot of work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm not misunderstanding the question, one concept you might wanna look into is generic/generated CRUD.

Netbeans has a primefaces CRUD generator [link](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nbpfcrudgen/)